# How to pull discount rate from if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, module

I need to calculate the total purchase price of the books. The discount is determined by the amount of books purchased. Those are split within the if statements. How can I have my code fully work? I am currently getting this error message:

[image: Error message that is displayed]

Here's my code:

```
BOOK_PRICE = 100

def main():
    numBooks = int(input("Enter the number of books you will be purchasing: "))
    discountPrice(numBooks)
    subTotalPrice(numBooks)
    #I have a problem getting the returned subTotal price
    totalPrice(theSubTotalPrice,discountRate)

def subTotalPrice (numBooks):
    theSubTotalPrice = numBooks * BOOK_PRICE
    print("Your subTotal is: $ ",theSubTotalPrice)
    return theSubTotalPrice
def totalPrice (theSubTotalPrice):
    theTotalPrice = theSubTotalPrice * discountRate
    print("Your Total Price is: $ ", theTotalPrice)
def discountPrice (numBooks):
    if numBooks <= 0 and numBooks <= 9:
        print(" ")
        discountRate = .00
        return discountRate
    if numBooks >= 10 and numBooks <= 19:
        print("Since you are ordering",numBooks,"books you will receive a 20% discount!")
        #how do any of these discountRates get put back to call them in a different module?
        discountRate = .20
        return discountRate
    if numBooks >= 20 and numBooks <= 49:
        print("Since you are ordering",numBooks,"books you will receive a 30% discount!")
        discountRate = .30
        return discountRate
    if numBooks >= 50 and numBooks <= 99:
        print("Since you are ordering",numBooks,"books you will receive a 40% discount!")
        discountRate = .40
        return discountRate
    if numBooks >= 100:
        print("Since you are ordering",numBooks,"books you will receive a 50% discount!")
        discountRate = .50
        return discountRate
main()
```

Comment: I'm curious: isn't it more work to post a screenshot then it would be to paste the text? ;)

Comment: Not really, the snipping tool takes a few seconds!

Comment: I see :) But text is better. It looks better on various displays, contents can be searched, copying-and-pasting works, takes less storage and bandwidth... you should paste the text ;)

Comment: Copy and paste is a pain because you have add 4 spaces to each line to show properly here. But it's still better because we can paste your code to our own IDE and try to run your code.

Comment: You need to assign the output of the function to a variable. e.g. discount_price = discountPrice(numBooks).

Comment: @Joe there is the {} button on the tool ribbon, that when pressed on selected text, indents all properly

Comment: @joel thanks man; I guess I need to go through some of the help files/ knowledge database to find out these features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the edited code. The first error was that you were returning the values from the functions, but there was no variable being assigned to the return value. Variables created inside a function lives only inside the function. Study the code below and see what changes I made. Ask if you have questions. Also you had another bug. You have numBooks <=0 as a condition. It should be numBooks >= 0. One last thing, thanks for the copy and paste instead of screenshot.

```
BOOK_PRICE = 100

def main():
    numBooks = int(input("Enter the number of books you will be purchasing: "))
    discountRate = discountPrice(numBooks)
    theSubTotalPrice = subTotalPrice(numBooks)
    #I have a problem getting the returned subTotal price
    totalPrice(theSubTotalPrice,discountRate)

def subTotalPrice (numBooks):
    theSubTotalPrice = numBooks * BOOK_PRICE
    print("Your subTotal is: $ ",theSubTotalPrice)
    return theSubTotalPrice
def totalPrice (theSubTotalPrice, discountRate):
    totalDiscount = theSubTotalPrice * discountRate
    theTotalPrice = theSubTotalPrice - totalDiscount
    print("Your Discount is: $ ", totalDiscount)
    print("Your Total Price is: $ ", theTotalPrice)
def discountPrice (numBooks):
    if numBooks >= 0 and numBooks <= 9:
        print(" ")
        discountRate = 0.00
        return discountRate
    if numBooks >= 10 and numBooks <= 19:
        print("Since you are ordering",numBooks,"books you will receive a 20% discount!")
        #how do any of these discountRates get put back to call them in a different module?
        discountRate = .20
        return discountRate
    if numBooks >= 20 and numBooks <= 49:
        print("Since you are ordering",numBooks,"books you will receive a 30% discount!")
        discountRate = .30
        return discountRate
    if numBooks >= 50 and numBooks <= 99:
        print("Since you are ordering",numBooks,"books you will receive a 40% discount!")
        discountRate = .40
        return discountRate
    if numBooks >= 100:
        print("Since you are ordering",numBooks,"books you will receive a 50% discount!")
        discountRate = .50
        return discountRate
main()
```

Here is what I get when I ran it with various inputs:

```
>>> 
===== RESTART: C:\Users\Joe\Desktop\scripts\Stack_overflow\book_price.py =====
Enter the number of books you will be purchasing: 9

Your subTotal is: $  900
Your Total Price is: $  0.0
>>> 
===== RESTART: C:\Users\Joe\Desktop\scripts\Stack_overflow\book_price.py =====
Enter the number of books you will be purchasing: 9

Your subTotal is: $  900
Your Total Price is: $  0.0
>>> 
===== RESTART: C:\Users\Joe\Desktop\scripts\Stack_overflow\book_price.py =====
Enter the number of books you will be purchasing: 19
Since you are ordering 19 books you will receive a 20% discount!
# I need to take these two values and subtract them. 1900(subtotal) - 380 (discountprice)
Your subTotal is: $  1900
Your Total Price is: $  380.0
>>> 
===== RESTART: C:\Users\Joe\Desktop\scripts\Stack_overflow\book_price.py =====
Enter the number of books you will be purchasing: 50
Since you are ordering 50 books you will receive a 40% discount!
Your subTotal is: $  5000
Your Total Price is: $  2000.0
>>>
```

Comment: This works, thanks. Now if I wanted to subtract the discount price from the subtotal how would I add that to it?

Comment: I edited the totalPrice function. Now the total discount is calculated, then I subtract the discount from theSubTotalPrice.

Answer (score 0):

Your last function is currently written as

```
def totalPrice(theTotalPrice):
```

but your argument should be

```
def totalPrice(numBooks):
```

In fact, you appear to pass the correct argument to this function in `main`, it is just a mistake in the actual function definition.

In general, if you see errors like "(some variable) is not defined", ensure that the variable is in scope, by passing the correct function arguments.

Comment: @Alina Make sure *all* of the variables are available in your function. You never passed in `discountRate` either. Read the error messages, they tell you *exactly* what the problem is.

Comment: I declared the discountRate in each if statement but that doesn't get passed through.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you're not giving your functions all the variables that they need. In `eligibleDiscounts` you reference a variable `totalPrice`. Where is that value being defined? Is it meant to be `BOOK_PRICE * numBooks`?

Similar thing in `totalPrice`. If you want it to know about `numBooks`, you need to pass `numBooks` in.

I think what you want to do is calculate the `totalPrice`, and pass that into `eligibleDiscount`. Then have `eligibleDiscount` return `discountRate`. I.e. end with `return discountRate`. Which should be defined under each `if`/`elif` statement. Not just the last one.

Then pass everything into `totalPrice`.

Comment: Okay, I'll rewrite and update shortly if I can figure it out.

Comment: I've updated my original code and made notes where I have trouble. Do you  have any idea how I can fix it?